# Workspace.DeleteMapping Method Throws When Given a Mapped Path

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk

I'm using TFS SDK. I mapped a project with TFS on Visual Studio. And in my code, I check the server path and local path is mapped already? Their values are true, but  workspace.DeleteMapping() method throws when I try to delete the mapped path.

It says "Doesn't find any mapping in [local path]" . But workspace.IsLocalPathMapped(LocalFolder) method returns true value?

```
WorkingFolder workfolder = new WorkingFolder(ServerFolder, LocalFolder);
workspace = workspaces[0];
if (workspace.IsServerPathMapped(ServerFolder) && workspace.IsLocalPathMapped(LocalFolder))
{
    workspace.DeleteMapping(workfolder);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IsServerPathMapped and IsLocalPathMapped tell you if a given server path or local path is *underneath* (or equivalent to) one of the workspace mappings.  For instance, let's say you had a recursive mapping set up like this:

```
C:\dev\project -> $/TeamProject/Main
```

If you ran IsServerPathMapped on the item "$/TeamProject/Main/Solution/foo.cs" it would return true because that file lies underneath one of your recursive mappings.  The IsServerPathMapped function is asking "If I do a GetLatest will this file be in my workspace" and here the answer is yes.

If you can explain a little bit more about what your trying to accomplish with this code, I may be able to point you at different APIs to use.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. 

I still working about "get latest" and "build" projects with TFS SDK.

On our server, all project mapped already. And  When I used workspace.Get() method, it will get latest version all of project in workspace. But I want that, it brings only selected project. 

I tried deleting mapping projects in workspace and I create mapping only selected project but I couldn't.

Comment: What does your mappings look like?  I assume you are saying that you have $/ mapped to some local drive.  You want to start by removing the mapping for $/ and then adding a mapping for $/TeamProject (or deeper in the tree if that is what you want).

Comment: Exactly as you said. I have $/ mapped to my local but I want to get latest $/TeamProject to my local. Therefore, I tried deleting mapping $/ and creating mapping with $/TeamProject